# Azure Storage Table Query, Which is faster?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Very simple lookup, use A to lookup B, A is unique value in whole table, B is unique value in whole table as well

**method 1:**

```
PartionKey => A
RowKey => B
```

lookup by `TOP(1) PartionKey eq "A"`

**method 2:**

```
PartionKey => A
RowKey => "" (empty string)
Value => B
```

lookup by `TOP(1)  (PartionKey eq "A") and (RowKey eq "")`

**method 3:**

```
PartionKey => "" (empty string)
RowKey => A 
Value => B
```

lookup by `TOP(1)  (PartionKey eq "") and (RowKey eq "A")`

**Question: Which is faster?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In method #2, the row key is empty, but you're query specifies a non-empty row key (of "B"). Did you mean `and (RowKey eq "")`? If so, that method is faster, in that it will always return a result. Method #1 may return an empty result set with a continuation token, at which point you have to make a second query to actually get at the data.

Comment: yes, I mean `""`. Thanks. I will always use `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` together. I also put a method 3 there. Compare `Pk=A and Rk=""` with `Pk="" and Rk=A`, which is faster? If query amount is huge, which method do you recommend?

Comment: If you're specifying both partition key and row key, I don't think the actual values (empty string or not) will have any effect on performance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question…  If A is a unique value across the whole table, B’s uniqueness is irrelevant. So you are better off, scalability wise, to split A in two, and use the first part as the Partition Key and the second part as the Row Key.

It is important to understand that in Azure table storage, PartitionKey + RowKey is analogous  to the Primary Key in an SQL database, and it’s most efficient to use the whole primary key for a lookup.